# Проблема с адаптацией всплывающей формы на fancybox

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, fancybox

Работаю сейчас над сайтом http://centralibrary.com/.

При нажатии на кнопку "Индивидуальный заказ" всплывает форма заказа. Пытался как-то её по ширине адаптировать под телефон. С ПК вроде всё работает, ширина подстраивается. Через инструменты разработчика выбирал разные устройства - тоже всё хорошо. С телефона открываю и стили будто совсем отваливаются, на форму вообще не применяются, хотя в том же файле лежат, что и для остального сайта.

[image: скрин с телефона]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отладки на телефоне можна использовать встроеные "Инструменты разработчика" в браузер, там есть возможность выбрать размер окна и увидеть что у вас не так с кодом.Вот у вас при размере окна 480рx блок с класом .fancybox-close, я б `.fancybox-close{width: 35px;height: 35px`} зделал.

Comment: Тут не в этом проблема. Через "Инструменты разработчика" форма отображается более или менее корректно, а на телефоне всё совсем плохо. То есть то, что показывает браузер на маленьком разрешении, не соответствует тому, что видно на телефоне

Comment: Для модального окна у вас стоить style .indorder_modal{ min-width:0px; а width по умолчанию 991px}. Это те стили которые видят браузеры - можна увидеть Панель разработчика -> Elements-> Computed. там указаны  все стили которые дейстувют на выбраный элемент

Comment: Да, я знаю как это всё работает. Значение width меняется вместе с сужением экрана ниже 991px, подстраиваясь под экран. Просто на телефоне этого не происходит. В том и аномалия.
Либо мы всё-таки говорим о разных вещах.

Comment: У вас есть дописано стили к class - fancybox-desktop, и он добавляеться только если сайт открыт на ПК, если его открыть на мобильном то даного класа нету а есть уже - fancebox- mobile а к нему нету стилей

Comment: Ага, точно. Спасибо большое! Я как-то и не заметил, что классы пропадают.

Comment: Посмотрите так же нету ли других сторонних класов - например fancybox- table